# Ordenando coluna de DataTable por um campo do tipo DateTime

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-datatables, datatable

Tenho o seguinte campo na minha model:

```
[Required]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? DataCadastro { get; set; }
```

Uso o DisplayFormat para formatar e exibir a data no formato brasileiro posteriormente em uma DataTable.
Porém não está sendo ordenado corretamente. Preciso colocar mais alguma coisa no dataTable ?

```
$('#table-controle').html(data);
dataTable = $('#table-controle').dataTable({
    "language": {
        "url": "../../../Content/json/Portuguese-Brasil.json"
    }
});
```

Comment: Tem como colocar seu código aqui no [Jsfidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Raphael, um conselho, a menos que esteja fazendo algo trivial, como popular um textbox, evite formatar valores no lado do servidor, blibiotecas como o datatables trabalham melhor com o json sofrendo o minimo de inteferencia possivel. no seu caso , acredito que o melhor seja utilizar o seguinte plugin do datatables [`datetime`](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/datetime) em conjunto com o [`columns.type`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) `date`

Comment: Encontrei a solução nesse post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124746/disable-automatic-sorting-on-the-first-column-when-using-jquery-datatables